# Data Science Project Manager - Planning

Tags: data

I'm a project manager and I've been tasked to work with a data scientists. As a project manager it's my role to create a plan which I will monitor and report against.

The data scientist has experience in his role however is struggling provide a breakdown of the work that he intends to do.

Example the initial task is to analyse customer data held on our database to identify potential insights.

Can data science projects be Project managed by identifying time constrained tasks?

Can you direct me towards some examples or resources which may help breakdown data science projects?

Comment: Appears to be a copy of https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24017/work-breakdown-of-data-project - I have made a suggestion there that you take this to other sites, as it is not a data science issue. Also see https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/can-alternative-sites-now-be-added-to-off-topic-migration where I am hoping we could make that easier to suggest for other users.

Answer (score 1):

See mine (and others) answers here regarding [how to work with a data scientist](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-work-with-a-data-scientist).

The problem you have with planning is real and severe. We all have a problem in planning research. As Albert Einstein said "If we knew what it was we were doing, it would not be called research, would it?".
Though it is hard, we are not the only one having to deal with uncertainty in planning. The common methods of dealing with uncertainty are useful here too. Your idea to break down the task is great. So is performing quick tests (POC like) in order to see is a direction is valuable.
The main problem in research that it is very common that good direction will be found to be not beneficial only after a lot of work. You might be surprised from the other side, having great ideas coming when somebody takes a shower.

Due to the problem in estimation, people hesitate to do it. Though, they realize that "You'll have it when it ready" is not an answer that a customer will accept.

The question is indeed not a pure data science question and so is my answer. Understand that planning is hard, do try to do so and expect your planning to be very inaccurate.